# Creating risk plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to create a risk communication plot in R using a 10 by 10 grid of 100 "people". There's a nice example here: http://static.www.bmj.com/content/bmj/351/bmj.h5496/F3.large.jpg.

Some simple data would be:

```
to.plot = data.frame(id=1:100, dead=rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Could you expand on the issue you're having?

Comment: My main problem is finding how to create in R (or import into R) images or symbols of sad/happy faces and/or stick people that can be coloured to show risk.

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/use-emoji-font-in-r/